# What is optional chaining (Elvis operator) in TypeScript and how does it work?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand what is optional chaining (Elvis operator) and how it works, and what it is used for in TypeScript?

```
public static getName(user: IUser){
    if(user.firstName != null && user.firstName != ""){
        return user.firstName;
    }

    if(user.lastName != null && user.lastName != ""){
        return user.lastName;
    }

    return user.username;
}
```

Could I, for example, apply optional chaining to the code above to make it shorter?

**-Edit-**

Updated the question with code, after comment.

```
export interface IUser {
    id: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    username: string;
}
```

Comment: What is `IUser`?

Comment: @jcalz it's an interface that acts as a model, I have updated and added the relevant code in the main question.

Comment: With that definition I'd suggest that you use `--strictNullChecks` and not worry about checking for `null`, since `null` and `undefined` are not in the domain of `string`.  If you expect the values to be `null`-ish, your interface definition should say that (e.g., make the properties optional?)

Answer (score 13):

## Optional Chaining operator

The optional chaining operator helps you write expressions that stops running as soon as `null` or `undefined` is encountered.

For example you can refactor your code like this if you want to check that user is not `null` or `undefined`:

```
public static getName(user: IUser): string {
    if(user?.firstName != null && user?.firstName != ""){
        return user.firstName;
    }

    if(user?.lastName != null && user?.lastName != ""){
        return user.lastName;
    }

    return user?.username || "";
}
```

What is really interesting is that you can use it with arrays and functions:

```
// Access first element of array if array is set
const element = array?.[0];

// Call function if set
myFunction.(args);
```

But in your case, the nullish coalescing operator is more suitable to shroten the code.

## Nullish Coalescing operator

The nullish coalescing operator acts like the logical operator `||` excepts that it fallbacks to the default value if the value checked equals `null` or `undefined` only. It prevents the bugs created with `||` when the value equals `0` or `Nan` because `||` only checks for nullish expression.

Here is what your code would look like:

```
public static getName(user: IUser){
    return user?.firstName ?? user?.lastName ?? user?.username ?? "";
}
```

Above both operators are used for a more robust code.

## More on the bugs the logical operator `||` can induce

Check this example: you create an app where a user can set a timer. The user can choose a time greater than `0`, but if he doesn't, you set a default time for them. This is how you get the time for the timer:

```
const time = userTime || defaultTime;
```

If the user enters a number strictly greater than 0, it works as you expect and `time === userTime`. But if they enter `0`, the logical operator `||` detects `0` as a nullish expression and fallbacks to `defaultTime`.

To avoid this, use the nullish coalescing operator that only fallbacks if `userTime` equals `null` or `undefined`:

```
const time = userTime ?? defaultTime;
```

The code above will work as expected.

Comment: Could you please give some more information regarding the bug with `||`? What would happen if I used `||`, what bug does occur?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the nullish coalescing operator.

```
function getFastname(user: IUser) {
    return user.firstName != "" ? user.firstName : null ?? 
    user.lastName != "" ? user.lastName: null ?? 
    user.username
}
```

It would be a lot smaller if you would not check for `""`, then you could do

```
function getFastname(user: IUser) {
    return user.firstName ?? user.lastName ?? user.username
}
```

and lastly with the boolean logical operator which also works for `""`

```
function getFastname(user: IUser) {
    return user.firstName || user.lastName || user.username
}
```